# I want to open a tensorflow model in chrome extension but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, json, tensorflow, google-chrome-extension

I added the model.json and the bin file at the same directory and allowed web access in the manifest.

However I can't load the file
It saids

```
Error: In local storage, there is no model with name 'model'
```

But I can find the file in the chrome extension DevTool

This is the code I use

```
mymodel = {the json model file}
async function load_model() {

    localStorage.setItem("model",JSON.stringify(mymodel));
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('localstorage://model');

    return model;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using localStorage.getItem pattern?

Comment: @noninertialframe yes I tried loadLayersModel(localStorage.getItem(model));